# Getting a property from current object to use the property value in another

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm looking on if its possible to get a property of an object and use it in another for example

```
let obj = {
  something:"a string",
  name:"a test obj
  info: {
       name: need the name above
   }
}
```

So in the last nested name i want the Name above to be in there too, i tried like this.name but no luck

Comment: `obj.info.name` ?

Comment: Put it into another variable. There's no way around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a different way to achieve your outcome you could use the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function on your object.

You basically create a method that will be run when you try to access a property on your object, you can intercept the call and return a different value, because it's at the root of your object it has the correct context to get the name property.

```js
let obj = {
  something:"a string",
  name:"a test obj",
  get info() {
    return {
      name: this.name
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj.info.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to reuse values like that just declare them as variables before creating the object:

```js
const name = 'Bob';

const obj = {
  something: 'a string',
  name,
  info: { name }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("BaseController", function($scope) { 
   let obj = {name:"a test obj"};
   obj = {something:"a string",name:"a test obj",
   info: {name:  obj.name}
};
  $scope.obj = obj;
   
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseController">
    {{obj}}
  </body>

</html>
```